# Cannot modify system configuration

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, polkit, ubuntu-mate

why i cannot add user after install vnc and add the polkit?
if i remove the polkit i able to add user from console but rdp didn't work.
please help.

here is the capture:

[image]

i am using ubuntu 18.04, mate desktop, vnc server
RDP from windows

here is my polkit:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if ((action.id == “org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device” || action.id == 
“org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile” || action.id == “org.freedesktop.
color-manager.delete-device” || action.id == “org.freedesktop.color-manager.dele
te-profile” || action.id == “org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device” || act
ion.id == “org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile”) && subject.isInGroup(“
sudo”))
{
return polkit.Result.YES;
}
});
```

thanks

---

@roaima you mean like this?
thanks for response

`polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" ||
  action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile" ||
  action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device" ||
  action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile" ||
  action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device" ||
  action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile") &&
  subject.isInGroup("{sudo}")) {
  return polkit.Result.YES;
 }
});`

Comment: polkit listing has spurious spaces

Comment: You're using fancy quotes `“...”` instead of ordinary double quotes `"..."`

Comment: @roaima i have changed with "..." and still have same error. is it this is correct parameter for: subject.isInGroup(“sudo”) should i change the sudo with group or user ?

Comment: Since you've got no answers I'd suggest you update your question to show the fixed polkit entry without the "smart quotes". (Don't forget to indent with four spaces to keep the code formatting.)

Comment: Ubuntu's polkit version doesn't support those rules. [It's still on 0.105](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=polkit), which is before the JavaScript based-rules syntax was added.

Comment: @muru 
owh ok .....i have checked my pkaction version 0.105